# Finding pair of students with same marks in sql

Tags: sql

So there is this table in **Sql** `student(name,roll,department,marks)`. I had to find pairs of students having same marks(assuming pairs exists).
 What i did was:

```
select student.name,
    x.name,
    x.marks
from student,
    student x
where student.marks = x.marks
    and student.name != x.name
```

o/p was:

```
alice      Alex     40
sam        jack     30
jack       sam      30
Alex       alice    40
```

Question is how can I remove the duplicate ones?

Comment: select distinct

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` won't work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this using `<` (or `>`) instead to make sure that reverse match is not included.

```
select t.name,
    x.name,
    x.marks
from student t
join student x on t.marks = x.marks
   and t.name < x.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using '!=' between names, just use a '<' which would stand true only once.

```
select student.name,
    x.name,
    x.marks
from student,
    student x
where student.marks = x.marks
    and student.name < x.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

`'<'` works fine, you can use your query as below :

```
SELECT A.Name,
    B.Name,
    B.Marks
from Student A
LEFT JOIN Student B ON A.Marks=B.Marks AND B.Name < A.Name 
WHERE B.Marks IS NOT NULL
```

Thanks